# Does anyone know the name of custom fields when switching from PayPal IPN to PayPal Webhooks?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

In Paypal IPN, I have a custom field when I am receiving a `txn.type == subscr_payment` message that is called `option_selection2`
(The input name on the html form is called "os1" by PayPal).

On a cancellation or expiration message type, that same field is called `option_selection1`

Does anyone know what these two fields (or really one field in two different situations) are named in **PayPal WebHooks**?  And any documentation from PayPal that shows these names?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I couldn't find these documented.

Comment: Webhooks isn't for integrations that use those particular fields

Comment: Really?  So you cannot get all of the same fields from PayPal Webhooks as you can from PayPal IPN?  So its inferior in that way it sounds like.  Is there a reference that shows the field differences between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PayPal Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/) are for REST payments that use a clientID.

No such integrations have the classic fields you mention. So none of those fields are applicable to webhooks.